# Trouble when publish a website to online from local server

Tags: linux, networking, website

i has a website host on Linux server Centos 7 in my office, and i wanna publish this website to internet, i had a Domain name ( training.gbc-engineers.com ) and point A Record to my publish WAN IP address, i already config on Firewall open all port for this linux Server . But in my local network this website has another name is moodle.gbcvn2.local ( local domain ) now when i try to type training.gbc-engineers.com it's alway direct to moodle.gbcvn2.local and can not access website from outside even i use WAN IP still direct to this address. already try from 4G ( outside local network ), another network ... still same issued.

i has 2 Vitrual hostfile

File 1:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin moodle@gbc-engineers.com
        ServerName moodle.gbcvn2.local
        DocumentRoot /var/www/moodle

        ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/moodle.error.log"
        CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/moodle.log" combined

        <Directory> /var/www/moodle>
                AllowOverride None
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

File 2:

```
<VirtualHost *:80 >

        ServerAdmin training@gbc-engineers.com
        ServerName training.gbc-engineers.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/moodle

        ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/moodle.error.log"
        CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/moodle.log" combined

        <Directory> /var/www/moodle>
                AllowOverride None
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

even i remove File 1 it's still doesn't work.
my local domain is gbcvn2.local and gbc-engineers.com is bought from provider

Comment: But both of your virtualhost blocks actually point to the same DocumentRoot. So isn't the result normal?

Comment: Thanks Grawity for reply,

i could delete 1, no need to keep both i just wanna publish my website and point to training.gbc-engineers.com. But i try and it doesn't work. do i need config something on DNS server ? my DNS server have domain gbcvn2.local

Comment: Are you saying you want to publish the same Moodle system on both domains?

Comment: Dear Grawity, yes that correct my question sorrry.
i found the issued is i need to fix inside file config.php in side moodle installation folder $CFG->wwwroot to correct domain address


$CFG->wwwroot   = 'http://training.gbc-engineers.com';
$CFG->dataroot  = '/var/www/moodledata';
$CFG->admin     = 'admin';

now people from outside could access with address training.gbc-engineers.com but local network can not anymore. could i push both variable for $CFG ?

Answer (score 0):

Moodle only supports being hosted on **one** domain at a time. The domain must be configured in `config.php` as you found, and the webapp itself will always redirect your browser to what it thinks is the correct domain.

The domain also must be updated in the database itself, as links in Moodle pages use full URLs (containing the old domain) – see the [Moodle migration](https://docs.moodle.org/en/Moodle_migration) article, specifically the part about [database update](https://docs.moodle.org/37/en/Moodle_migration#Update_links_containing_wwwroot_in_the_database), for instructions about how to do this.

---

If the server has a private address but your second domain points to your router's WAN address, usually connections to the WAN address will work only *from outside* of the LAN. This is due to the way NAT works (or rather, cannot work) inside the same subnet.

To avoid this, you'll need either a "split DNS" system where the same domain resolves to different addresses inside/outside the LAN, or your router will need a "NAT hairpin" / "NAT loopback" feature.

Comment: Thanks you , may be no need 2 domain for Moodle , 1 is enough but i don't know why i could not access to moodle anymore from local network , but outside of network could.